# OBS encoder overloaded when streaming, but not when just recording

Tags: video, performance, streaming, obs-studio

I have a 1080p screen and can record it smoothly with OBS while playing games. However, when I livestream, I quickly get a message "recorder overloaded". It works somewhat when nothing is running except OBS, but as soon as I start anything, I get that message. Streaming in 720p30 streaming works fine, 1080p60 recording works fine, but both together (OBS can record at a different resolution than the streaming resolution) don't work.
It's not a false warning, the stream does have dropped frames and increasing delay. It's also not a matter of slow internet, mine should be enough for 6 simultaneous livestreams. Even if I lower the bitrate to the lowest possible setting in OBS, I still get the warning.

Does streaming really take so many resources? Is it possible that I have accidentally set something that makes OBS encode the video twice, for recording and for streaming? Is there some tweak or trick I can do to make it run smoothly?

Here is some setup information, whatever seemed relevant:

Laptop model: https://geizhals.de/schenker-xmg-a507-vsy-10504411-a1686447.html

```
Debian 9.9
OBS 23.2.1 (compiled, because Synaptic only contains version 0.0.1)
streaming to YouTube
stream key… haha, no
encoder "FFMPEG VAAPI" (runs MUCH smoother than x264, so it is using the graphics card)
"Enforce streaming service encoder settings" enabled (also tried with it disabled)
"Rescale output" disabled (also tried with 360p and setting 1080p for the recording)
Bitrate: 5000 Kbps (also tried with 50)
Recording type "Standard"
recording path on SSD
format MKV
recording uses stream encoder (also tried with custom, using my default stream settings while using different settings for the stream)
base and output resolution both 1920×1080
bilinear scaling
60 fps
no added stream delay
```

Comment: superuser.com recommended using the [tag:video-streaming] tag, but the description sounded more like a tag for video streams from cameras, capture cards, etc. Would it be applicable here?

Comment: *Is it possible that I have accidentally set something that makes OBS encode the video twice, for recording and for streaming?* -- As a comment, you're changing the resolution so the stream would have to be encoded twice, as far as I am aware. Not that it likely makes much difference in that streaming/recording would likely be two separate processes anyway.

Comment: Where am I changing the resolution? I plan on using the screen resolution for both recording and streaming. But it lags with 1080 recording while streaming in 1080p or 720p, only 720p streaming+recording works smoothly (or 1080p recording without streaming).

Comment: "Changing the resolution" might be wrong way to word it. You are processing two separate frames as far as I am aware. Another thing to possibly consider is the speed at which you are able to upload video. Larger frames mean more data to process and send.

Comment: As I said, the internet speed is not the issue. And is there a way to **not** process two separate frames at once?